# Несколько массивов в одну переменную в php

Tags: php, массивы

Очень глупый вопрос, но все же. Возможно ли объединить несколько массивов под одной переменной?
Например:
`$a = [1, 2, 3];
 $b = [4, 5, 6];`
Чтоб в итоге вышло:
`$c = [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6];`

Comment: ``$c = [$a, $b]``?

Comment: Так `$c = [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6];` не выйдет, но выйдет так как в комментарии выше..

Comment: @xEdelweiss я работаю с очень вредным api, и он не хочет такое принимать, ему нужны не вложенные массивы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если сделать так: `$c = [$a, $b];`, то получится `$c = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];`

Можно ещё получить не два вложенных массива, а один общий, вот так: `$c = array_merge($a, $b);`. Получим `$c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];`

Answer (score 0):

Можно, использовав двойной массив:

```
$c = [$a, $b]
```